# ASP.NET Web Page With Gridview Shows Data That Does Not Exist In SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Since I got ZERO hits Google'ing this, I thought I would pose the situation to the vast stackoverflow brain trust for comment because I am as freaked out as if I had seen a real ghost.

I have a simple ASP.NET web page with a gridview control which I use to display (essentially sales order) data queried from a SQL Server database table.  The code behind (most likely some copy/paste/tweak from stackoverflow articles) looks like:

```
  _SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(_SelQuery, _Cnxn);
  _SqlCmd.Connection.Open();
  _SqlRdr =
      _SqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
  _DataTbl = new DataTable();
  _DataTbl.Load(_SqlRdr);
  :
  :
  GridView TgtGrid;
  TgtGrid.DataSource = _DataTbl;
  TgtGrid.DataBind();
```

_SelQuery is a string containing a SQL command using a WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE [Month] = '1' AND [Year] = '2014'
```

This morning (Feb 7, 2014) the boss says, 'Hey, Jan 2014 has no data.'  I verified Jan 2014 had no data.  I talked to my partner in crime - who actually creates the data - and he said, "There is no Jan 2014 data, it got deleted and I'm trying to figure out why."

A little later, I visited the page again, selected 'January' and '2014', hit 'Update', and got some sparse data back (I have the screen shot to prove this). I asked my cohort, 'You must be rebuilding the Jan data, right?'  He had NOT began rebuilding the data and had NOT even fixed the code so he could rebuild the data.

I loaded the project in VWD 2008 Express on my computer and ran the page - no data.  I put a break point in the code, copied the SQL command, and tried it in SQL Server Studio - again, no data.  Back to the real website to try other months - appeared normal, except Jan 2014 got sparse data.

The thing I couldn't do is run the real website in debug mode in VWD 2008 (perhaps a bit of ignorance on my part?), but the files involved had the same date/time stamp as my local copies.  So I put some debug code in to display the SQL command being used to query the data.  It is EXACTLY the same as generated by my machine running the local copy of the page in debug mode.

After that long wind up, the big questions:

1) Has anybody ever seen anything like this?
2) I can imagine many scenarios where existing data would NOT be returned, but what - in the non-paranormal realm - could explain this non-existent data being returned?
3) Is there any kind of IIS caching that could explain it?

Any comments greatly appreciated.  This data is shown to the executive committee of a Fortune 100 company and I seriously doubt they will be 'cool' with it being wrong...

Comment: I've never heard of any caching mechanisms that would describe what you see.  Have you run the query in SSMS on the actual database to prove what data currently exists?

Comment: I cant think of any caching that would do that, so I'd recommend running a trace on the SQL server to see *exactly* what queries are being executed by the production code and make sure there aren't any bugs there. Is your SQL server load balanced or replicated?

Comment: It is a single SQL server and both production and my local debug project are all pointed at the same server.  In order to introduce debug code on the production server that would show the query being used, I obviously had to modify the code there.  However, after that, both production and debug project were using the exact same queries.  Now, the Jan data has been restored so I can't really replicate the problem.  But what I saw was downright paranormal.  Things like that just can't happen in real life.